# Ordering of keys in expandablelistview android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am creating a hashmap and adding keys in it in the order i want to display in expandable listview. Below is the code for putting string in hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> example= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        example.put(cnt.getString(R.string.first), first_summary);
        example.put(cnt.getString(R.string.second), second_summary);
        example.put(cnt.getString(R.string.third), third_summary);
```

But when i am adding it to listview then second is coming before first.How can i insert in expandablelistview in the order i have defined the keys?

Below is the code for expandablelistview creation:

```
 public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertview, ViewGroup parentview) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String group_title = (String) getGroup(parent);
    if(convertview == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertview = inflator.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parentview,false);
    }
    TextView parent_textview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
    parent_textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    parent_textview.setText(group_title);
    return convertview;
}
```

Can you guide please?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `ExpandableListView`'s fault .`HashMap` has not the notion of order. Try using a [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). From the doc

> LinkedHashMap is an implementation of Map that guarantees iteration
>   order. All optional operations are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `HashMap` with `LinkedHashMap`

In your code replace

`HashMap<String, List<String>> example= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();`

with

`LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> example = new LinkedHashMap<>();`